# Azure devops build pipeline- publish artifact process

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created the azure build pipeline for my website application. In this, there is a task of Publish Artifact Which I think supposed to publish a website. But right now it is publishing without the dlls. Means it contains the *.aspx and *.aspx.cs files. It supposed to create the dll files for *.aspx.cs files. Could you please let me know which publish option/task I am supposed to choose for my website. Which will be equivalent to the "Publish Web App" command in the azure build pipeline.

Comment: can you provide some information on Build Pipeline, what template & how/where it is deploying?

Answer (score 1):

> right now it is publishing without the dlls. Means it contains the
> *.aspx and *.aspx.cs files.

For this issue, I tested publishing the website to local in vs. From the local file directory, we can see that the dll files are in the `Bin` folder.  You can set the `system.debug=true` variable when running the pipeline, so you can track which folder the dll files are published to in the build solution step in the log.

[image]
[image]

About publishing artifact process:

Artifacts are the files that you want your build to produce. Publish artifact task is used to publish artifacts for the Azure Pipeline.

In the agent there are 3 folders: `a`, `b` and `s`. The variable `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` point to folder `a` (artifacts). When you build the code all the code and the artifacts exist on folder `s` (sources), the best practice is to copy only the artifacts to folder `a` and then use the task "`Publish build artifacts`", in this task you take the artifacts from folder `a` and put them on Azure DevOps storage or in your file share.

If you save the artifacts in Azure DevOps you can access your artifacts from the build summary page or create a release pipeline. if you save them in a file share you can just access them there or in the release pipeline.

In addition, you can share your build definition and msbuild arguments for further investigation.

Comment: Your answer cleared some of my doubts hence the upvote. Could you please help me in understanding whats the difference between Visual studio publish of a project and the Dev ops publish artifact?  Visual studio publish generates only deployable files while Azure Devops publish generates even .cs , .bat files in the file share. How do I get only deployable files in the Publish task instead of adding file extension restrictions in the Copy task?  Thanks in Advance